# Regex max a string till " and not stop at \"

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String to be checked for regex :

```
"field":"Testing, for something \"and something\""
```

which I want to pattern match and replace with :

```
"field":"SAFE"
```

For this, I am trying to pattern match and capture till the last inverted commas. I have tried the following regex, but its not matching :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"field\":\".*?(?!\\\")\"");
```

New to regex, can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT :
I guess the question was not clear. Apologies. The above is not the end of the string. It can contain more fields in succession :

```
"field":"Testing, for something \"and something\"", "new_field":"blahblah", ...
```

output should be :

```
"field":"SAFE", "new_field":"blahblah", ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\"field\":\"Testing, for something \\\"and something\\\"\"";
        str = str.replaceAll("(\"field\":).*", "$1\"SAFE\"");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"field":"SAFE"
```

**Explanation:**

1. `(\"field\":)` is the first capturing group
2. `.*` specifies all characters
3. `$1` specifies the first capturing group

---

### Update:

Writing this update based on the clarification from OP.

You can use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for comma as shown below:

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\"field\":\"Testing, for something \\\"and something\\\"\", \"new_field\":\"blahblah\"";
        str = str.replaceAll("(\"field\":).*(?=,)", "$1\"SAFE\"");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"field":"SAFE", "new_field":"blahblah"
```

Comment: Hi, I think I have a bit of confusion here. I don't want it to mark all the characters, I want it to mark till it encounters a " without a slash before it. There may be characters after it which I don't want matched : eg. : 
"field":"Testing, for something \"and something\"", "new_field":"blahblah"...

Comment: @Maverick - I've posted an update based on your clarification.

Comment: Hey, apologies for the late comment, it has been a busy couple of weeks for me. The answer you mentioned will stop at `Testing,` where it encounters the first comma, while it should go till the end of the value. I guess, there is no easy solution for this using regex. I can do a positive look ahead for `"` but that would again go till `Testing, for something "` where it gets the first `"`. Tried other permutations using negative lookahead but it still doesn't work for all cases.
Upvoting as it gave me new insights helpful in other use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/871600482ac56739a8106b7357ab2309ba9d4143).

```php
$str = '"field":"Testing, for something \"and something\""';
echo preg_replace('/(\"field\":\")(.*)(\")/i', "$1SAFE$3", $str);
```

Regex is tested: [here](https://regex101.com/r/lKXdW2/1/).